# Expected LPAREN error when trying to loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
    files <- Sys.glob("*.csv")
    test <- data.frame()
    for file in files {
      sally <- read.csv(file, colClasses = c(status_id = "factor", text = "character"))
      test <- rbind(test, sally)
    }
```

In line 3 I'm getting the following error:

```
    unexpected token 'file', expected 'LPAREN'
```

I've never had this issue with for loops before. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't formatted the `for` statement properly.  You have

```
for file in files {
```

when you need

```
for (file in files) {
```

The `LPAREN` in the error message is short for "left parenthesis", i.e. `(`.

Comment: Oh, gosh. That's me being totally mixed up between Python and r. Thank you.